# Cannot write files using ofstream

Tags: c++, file, filestream

I got a problem with my code, I basically want to write files to a path but it doesn't seems to work. Here's the code:

```
void WriteOnFile(const char *path)
{
    ofstream filetolog;
    filetolog.open(path);
    if (filetolog)
        filetolog<< "--[[ Test ]]\n";
}
```

and then I call WriteOnFile like that:

```
WriteOnFile("C:/Logs/lua/testing/filename.lua");
```

but it doesn't work. I also tried without `if (filetolog)` but it's the same.
Could anyone help me please?

Comment: check if(filetolog.is_open()) is true.

Comment: Are you asking for all the circumstances that would cause `ofstream::open` to fail?  I'm guessing that "it doesn't work" means that your `if` evaluates to false.  Is that what you're saying?

Comment: Here's a similar topic with a working solution, hope this helps!
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9739948/write-a-file-in-a-specific-path-in-c

Answer (score 0):

Your code won't create the file if one of the folders "c:/Logs", "c:/Logs/lua", "c:/Logs/lua/testing" does not exist.

Comment: ok, but is there a way to create all of throses folders with one function? (because WriteOnFile gets called with folder names I don't know)

Comment: There is no portable standard way of creating folders with C++. Perhaps, the easiest non-portable, Windows way is system("mkdir " + strPath). Note, however, that here the strPath must use backslashes instead of slashes to separate folder names. For more complicated Windows way, please see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1530760/how-do-i-recursively-create-a-folder-in-win32